# Flat list scrollToIndex animation configuration

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Is there a way to modify the (default) animation when using [FlatList.scrollToIndex](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoindex)?

I'm using this to have a step-by-step scroll but it feels a bit clunky (slow) with the default animation. I would like to avoid animating the scroll myself if possible. But if that's the only option I would like to ear suggestions.